# no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries on a MacBook Pro2 Apple Silicon chip

Tags: docker, apple-silicon

I am not able to
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries on a MacBook Pro2 Apple Silicon chip error seen

```
docker pull eclipse-temurin:20-jre-alpine
20-jre-alpine: Pulling from library/eclipse-temurin
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the tags on dockerhub it seems like the `20-jre-alpine` tag is only available for `amd64` architechture.

If you do not have a specific reason to need an alpine based image there is the `20-jre` tag that has a linux/arm64/v8 version.

```bash
docker pull eclipse-temurin:20-jre
```

You can look at [this page](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/eclipse-temurin/tags?page=1) to see all tags for your architechture.

Comment: I understand your proposal, but I would like to understand how to use the -alpine image since our production builds will happen on Ubuntu and for development we use Mac. This seems to be inconvenient

Comment: @user352290 if you want to use the `-alpine` image you will need to build it yourself. The owners of `eclipse-temurin` do not provide an image fot the arm64 architechture.